# Are there different flavors of the knower paradox based on different epistemic types?

Tags: epistemology, paradox

The [knower paradox theme](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/epistemic-paradoxes/#KnoPar) has at least two known(!) instances:

1. This sentence is known to be not true.
2. This sentence is not known to be true.

The linked SEP article reports (2) as stronger than (1) modulo skepticism, at least. So the positioning of "not" seems to affect the "flavor" of the paradox to some extent.

Now, assume that [foundationalism](https://iep.utm.edu/foundationalism-in-epistemology/), [coherentism](https://iep.utm.edu/coherentism-in-epistemology/), and [infinitism](https://iep.utm.edu/inf-epis/) are all correct, at least one per each of some three overarching domains of discourse, or as [variously](https://spot.colorado.edu/%7Etooley/Foundherentism.pdf) [combined](https://bcmullins.github.io/images/ecej.pdf) (formulate them in ways that aren't mutually exclusive). Say that there is F-knowledge for foundationalism, C-knowledge for coherentism, and I-knowledge for infinitism. Do there then exist three more types of flavors of knower paradoxes, or seven more if combinations are allowed (or fourteen, to account for doubling over (1) and (2))? One for each of the following, that is:

3. This sentence is not F-known to be true.
4. This sentence is not C-known to be true.
5. This sentence is not I-known to be true.
6. This sentence is not FC-known to be true.
7. This sentence is not FI-known to be true.
8. This sentence is not CI-known to be true.
9. This sentence is not FCI-known to be true.
10. (through 16) This sentence is X-known to not be true.

Because of their self-reference, I wonder whether unknower sentences are best formulated like unto (4), though?<sup>**E**</sup> **Do the various regress-theoretic knowledge types make for multiple knower paradoxes, or should these paradoxes all turn on just C-knowledge (on account of the self-reference of unknower sentences)?**

---

<sup>**E**</sup>**Edit:** now that I think of it, "This sentence is not I-known to be true," seems, in fact, true, since that sentence is not inferred in the course of making an infinite sequence of inferences. So maybe not all the flavors of the unknower sentence cause logical indigestion?